# How to plot a sawtooth chirp waveform using an array of frequency and time for an FMCW radar?

Tags: python, continuous-signals, radar, time-domain

Before switching to use sawtooth I was using sine wave but in sine wave high frequency content was not clearly visible, But I don't have any experience with using sawtooth waveforms. I am going to make a custom block from this code in GNU Radio so I won't be able to use scipy.signal.sawtooth or signal.chirp. as some libraries don't work in GNU radio.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import pi

chirp_duration = 60e-6
f0 = 1e6 
f1 = 3e6 
no_samp = 1001
rcs = 0.0377

f_step = (f1-f0)/no_samp
rf_axis = np.linspace(f0, f1, int(f_step))
rt_axis = np.linspace(0, chirp_duration, int(f_step))

rchirp = np.cos(2 * np.pi * rf_axis * rt_axis)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 3))
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.title('Received Chirp')
plt.plot(rt_axis, rf_axis)
plt.show()
```

This is the code I was using to generate the chirp signal in sine wave. This code works perfectly for low frequency values of f0 and f1.

Comment: Did you forget to include the actual question?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 sorry for not being clear enough. I want to generate chirp signal using sawtooth wave without using scipy.signal.chirp

Comment: You are going to have to work on the wording of your question. For example, I don't know what a sawtooth chirp. And it is still not clear to me what exactly your are looking for help with. Are you trying to define a chirp waveform in python without using any modules besides numpy?